# Vue search v-data-table with computed values not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I am using computed values to fill my v-data-table and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the search property. I also want to make the columns sortable again if possible.

Here is my v-Data-Table:

```
 <v-data-table
      v-bind:search="search"
      v-bind:headers="headers"
      v-bind:items="myDataTransformed"
      class="elevation-1 mx-2"
    >
      <template v-slot:[`item.company`]="{ item }">
        <span>{{ item.company.name }}</span>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.trade`]="{ item }">
        <span>{{ item.trade.name }}</span>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.region`]="{ item }">
        <span>{{ item.region.name }}</span>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.project`]="{ item }">
        <span>{{ item.project.name }}</span>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.rating`]="{ item }">
        <v-rating readonly length="5" :value="item.rating"></v-rating>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.manager`]="{ item }">
        <span>{{ item.manager.name }}</span>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.coordinator`]="{ item }">
        <v-menu :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-width="200" offset-x>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          
            <v-btn
            class="pl-0 ml-0 mr-1 pr-1"
              v-model="menu"
              @click="getCoordinatorsInfo(item.coordinator)"
              text
              v-bind="attrs"
              v-on="on"
            >
            
              <span class="mx-0 px-0"><v-icon class="mr-1" >mdi-account</v-icon>{{ item.coordinator.name }} </span>
              
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-row wrap class="mb-1">
              <v-list>
                <v-list-item>
                  <v-avatar class="mx-3 mt-3" color="primary">
                    <span size="36" class="white--text text-h5">{{selCoordinatorInitials}}</span>
                  </v-avatar>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                      <h1 class="mt-5">{{ item.coordinator.name }}</h1>
                    </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-row>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-row>
              <v-switch v-model="contactEdit" label="Edit" class="mx-3 px-3"
                >Edit</v-switch
              >
            </v-row>

            <v-list>
              <v-list-item>
                <v-span class="justify-center"
                  ><v-icon>mdi-email</v-icon></v-span
                >
                <v-list-item-action>
                  <v-text-field
                    :disabled="contactEdit != true"
                    v-model="selCoordinatorEmail"
                    color="primary"
                    label="Email"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-list-item-action>
              </v-list-item>
              <v-list-item>
                <v-span class="justify-center"
                  ><v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon></v-span
                >
                <v-list-item-action>
                  <v-text-field
                    :disabled="contactEdit != true"
                    class="px-0 mx-0"
                    v-model="selCoordinatorPhone"
                    color="primary"
                    label="Phone Number"
                  ></v-text-field>
                </v-list-item-action>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <!-- <v-btn text @click="menu=false"> Cancel </v-btn> -->
              <v-btn
                :disabled="contactEdit != true"
                color="primary"
                text
                @click="updateContact(item.coordinator)"
              >
                UPDATE CONTACT
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-menu>
        <!-- <v-btn text>{{ item.coordinator.name }}</v-btn> -->
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.entryid`]="{ item }">
        <v-btn>{{ item.entryid }}</v-btn>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
        <!-- <v-btn
          @click="editEntry(item.entryid)"
          :value="item.actions"
          text
          icon
          small
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn> -->

        <v-btn
          @click="deleteEntry(item.entryid)"
          text
          icon
          small
          :value="item.actions"
          ><v-icon color="red">mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn
        >
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
import db from "@/firebase";

export default {
  name: "Home",

  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      menu: false,
      contactEdit: false,
      selCoordinatorEmail: "",
      selCoordinatorPhone: "",
      selCoordinatorInitials: "",
      //DATABASE INFOMATION
      reviews: [],
      companies: [],
      trades: [],
      regions: [],
      projects: [],
      rating: [],
      managers: [],
      coordinators: [],

      deletedItem: "",
      dialogDelete: false,
      database: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Company",
          align: "start",
          sortable: true,
          value: "company",
        },
        { text: "Trade", sortable: true, value: "trade" },
        { text: "Region", sortable: true, value: "region" },
        { text: "Project", sortable: true, value: "project" },
        { text: "Rating", sortable: true, value: "rating" },
        { text: "B&G VDC Manager", sortable: true, value: "manager" },
        { text: "Trade Coordinator", sortable: true, value: "coordinator" },
        { text: "Comments", sortable: true, value: "comment" },
        { text: "Actions", sortable: true, value: "actions" },
        { text: "EntryId", sortable: true, value: "eid", align: " d-none" },
        //{ text: 'EntryId', value: 'entryid', }
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getDatabase() {
      let result = await db.collection("db").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const reviewList = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        //reviewList[item.id] = item.data();
        reviewList.push({ data: item.data(), id: item.id });
        console.log("Review Ids: ", item.id);
      }
      this.reviews = reviewList;
      console.log("Database Information: ", this.reviews);
      return result;
    },
    async getCompanies() {
      let result = await db.collection("Company").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const companyHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        companyHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.companies = companyHash;
      // console.log("Company Names & Ids: ", this.companies);
      return result;
    },
    async getTrades() {
      let result = await db.collection("Trades").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const tradeHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        tradeHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.trades = tradeHash;
      // console.log("Trade Name & Ids: ", this.trades);
      return result;
    },
    async getRegions() {
      let result = await db.collection("Region").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const regionHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        regionHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.regions = regionHash;
      // console.log("Region Name & Ids: ", this.regions);
      return result;
    },
    async getProjects() {
      let result = await db.collection("Projects").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const projectHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        projectHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.projects = projectHash;
      // console.log("Project Name & Ids: ", this.projects);
      return result;
    },
    async getManagers() {
      let result = await db.collection("VDC Manager").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const managerHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        managerHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.managers = managerHash;
      // console.log("Manager Name & Ids: ", this.managers);
      return result;
    },
    async getCoordinators() {
      let result = await db.collection("TradeCoordinator").get();
      const docs = result.docs;
      const coordinatorHash = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const item = docs[i];
        coordinatorHash[item.id] = item.data();
      }
      this.coordinators = coordinatorHash;
      console.log("Coordinator Name & Ids: ", this.coordinators);
      return result;
    },
    getCoordinatorsInfo(doc) {
      (this.contactEdit = false),
        db.collection("TradeCoordinator").doc(doc.id).get();
      const firstLetters = doc.name
        .split(" ")
        .map((word) => word[0])
        .join("");
      this.selCoordinatorInitials = firstLetters;
      this.selCoordinatorEmail = doc.email;
      this.selCoordinatorPhone = doc.phone;
    },
    updateContact(doc) {
      console.log(
        doc.id,
        " Email: ",
        this.selCoordinatorEmail,
        " Phone: ",
        this.selCoordinatorPhone
      );
      db.collection("TradeCoordinator").doc(doc.id).update({
        email: this.selCoordinatorEmail,
        phone: this.selCoordinatorPhone,
      });
    },

    deleteEntry(doc) {
      this.dialogDelete = true;
      this.deletedItem = doc;
      console.log("doc: ", doc);
    },
    deleteItemConfirm() {
      //delete entry when button pressed
      console.log("deleted item: " + this.deletedItem);
      db.collection("db")
        .doc(this.deletedItem)
        .delete()
        .then(function () {
          console.log("Document sucessfully deleted!");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
        });
      this.closeDelete();
      this.getDatabase();
    },
    closeDelete() {
      this.dialogDelete = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      });
    },
    editEntry(doc) {
      //edit entry when selectedd
      console.log("doc: ", doc);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getDatabase();
    this.getCompanies();
    this.getTrades();
    this.getRegions();
    this.getProjects();
    this.getManagers();
    this.getCoordinators();
    this.getCoordinatorsInfo();
  },
  components: {},
  computed: {
    myDataTransformed() {
      const reviews = this.reviews.map((review) => {
        return {
          company: {
            ...this.companies[review.data.company_id],
            id: review.data.company_id,
          },
          trade: {
            ...this.trades[review.data.trade_id],
            id: review.data.trade_id,
          },
          region: {
            ...this.regions[review.data.region_id],
            id: review.data.region_id,
          },
          project: {
            ...this.projects[review.data.project_id],
            id: review.data.project_id,
          },
          rating: review.data.rating,
          manager: {
            ...this.managers[review.data.manager_id],
            id: review.data.manager_id,
          },
          coordinator: {
            ...this.coordinators[review.data.coordinator_id],
            id: review.data.coordinator_id,
          },
          entryid: review.id,
          comment: review.data.comment,
          date: review.data.date,
        };
      });
      console.log("Reviews: ", reviews);
      return reviews;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I have found a similar solution here.

[search doesn't work because of array (Vue + Vuetify <v-data-table>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100494/search-doesnt-work-because-of-array-vue-)

However, i was hoping to fix the search without a large restructure from what i have now...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here. My data is now sortable and searchable.

Updated Code:

```
headers: [
        {
          text: "Company",
          align: "start",
          sortable: true,
          value: "company.name",
        },
        { text: "Trade", sortable: true, value: "trade.name" },
        { text: "Region", sortable: true, value: "region.name" },
        { text: "Project", sortable: true, value: "project.name" },
        { text: "Rating", sortable: true, value: "rating" },
        { text: "B&G VDC Manager", sortable: true, value: "manager.name" },
        { text: "Trade Coordinator", sortable: true, value: "coordinator.name" },
        { text: "Comments", sortable: true, value: "comment" },
        { text: "Actions", sortable: true,align:"center", value: "actions" },
        { text: "EntryId", sortable: true, value: "eid", align: " d-none" },
```

[solution link stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845201/local-search-v-data-table-vuetify)